# Chrome Dev Tools - My javascript is cut off

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a MVC site with a large amount of Javascript in the page, and it begins towards the bottom. It is almost 500 lines of Javascript but when I right click -> inspect element and scroll to it I only see 260 lines with an ellipses (...) halfway through a method call (see the image).

This is causing a problem because when I use CTRL+F to find a line of Javascript beyond this point it is not found. Furthermore when I try to edit a line of Javascript by doubleclicking it the entire script gets highlighted and it jumps to the top, meaning I have to scroll down.

Has something changed with a recent update or have I enabled some setting by mistake somewhere? I'm sure it wasn't like this before.

[image]

UPDATE: I have confirmed this on a friend's machine.

Comment: What happens if you click on the ellipsis?

Comment: Nothing. If I double click the javascript becomes editable but jumps to the top of the script block.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "sources" tab. There you have full search functionality (`ctrl`+`f` on win, `cmd`+`f` on mac).

If you have such an enormous `<script>` tag, I'd suggest to change it to its own .js file.

Comment: Yes I know, but I cannot edit the Javascript in here.
External JS file yes ideally, but I have Razor code mixed in with it so that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience this in Chrome. Try to use Firefox and it does not cut the long javascript